# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref5.x') caused by order of setState functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```js
const [onePrices, setOnePrices] = useState([]);
const [twoPrices, setTwoPrices] = useState([]);
const [threePrices, setThreePrices] = useState([]);
const [fourPrices, setFourPrices] = useState([]);
const [fivePrices, setFivePrices] = useState([]);
const [terminal, setTerminal] = useState('0');

const dayToArray = {
  1: [onePrices, setOnePrices],
  2: [twoPrices, setTwoPrices],
  3: [threePrices, setThreePrices],
  4: [fourPrices, setFourPrices],
  5: [fivePrices, setFivePrices],
};

useEffect(() => {
  const setData = async () => {
    //dayToArray is a map which maps from a day to the corresponding
    //[state, setState] for that day
    const arr = dayToArray[day][0];
    const setArr = dayToArray[day][1];

    //If I already saved the values I don't want to query the API again
    if (arr.length > 0) {
      setTerminal(arrRef[arr.length - 1].val);
      return;
    }

    //Haven't gotten this data yet => query the API and store the data
    const data = await APIService(day, key);
    setArr(data);
    setTerminal(data[data.length - 1].val);
  };

  setData();
}, [day]);
```

In this order it generates the error, however, when I switch up the order of the state changes the error disappears.

```js
setTerminal(data[data.length - 1].val);
setArr(data);
```

I don't understand React Native that well and was wondering why I'm receiving this error and why swapping the order solves it. Also if I'm doing something stupid I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Please provide us with the whole component. ( containing where your states are define )

Comment: Where are you getting `day` from ? Please providing whole state